# both one-to-one and one-to-many relations of same type in ef core

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

My next question is regarding Entity Framework Core 2 (db - sql server) and having entities with both one-to-one and one-to-many of the same type.

I have these 2 entities:

Topic:

```
public class Topic
{
    [Key]
    public int TopicID { get; set; }
    public int MessageID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("MessageID")]
    public Message Message { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Message> Messages { get; set; }
}
```

Message:

```
public class Message
{
    [Key]
    public int MessageID { get; set; }
    public int TopicID { get; set; }
    public Topic Topic { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

And I set them up in my context like this:

```
builder.Entity<Topic>().HasKey(t => new { t.TopicID });
builder.Entity<Topic>()
    .HasOne(t => t.Message);
builder.Entity<Topic>()
    .HasMany(t => t.Messages)
    .WithOne(m => m.Topic);
builder.Entity<Message>().HasKey(m => new { m.MessageID });
builder.Entity<Message>()
    .HasOne(m => m.Topic)
    .WithMany(t => t.Messages);
```

So I have have both one-to-one and one-to-many relations of the same entity type:

- the topic has 1 main message and a list of messages (which are the replies).

When I try to create a new topic like this:

```
Message newMessage = new Message()
{
    Content = content
};
Topic newTopic = new Topic()
{
    Message = newMessage,
};

context.Topics.Add(newTopic);
context.SaveChanges();
```

- the topic gets created with a valid topicId
- the message gets created with a valid messageId
- the topic gets the new messageId
- but the message **does not get** the new topicId, instead it is **set to 0**

So the next thing I tried to to was create the new topic & message like this:

```
Message newMessage = new Message()
{
    Content = content
};
Topic newTopic = new Topic()
{
    Message = newMessage,
    Messages = new List<Message>() { newMessage }
};

context.Topics.Add(newTopic);
context.SaveChanges();
```

But then I received the following exception:

> fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update[10000]
>         An exception occurred in the database while saving changes for context type ‘MyContext'.
>         System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to save changes because a circular dependency was detected in the data to be saved:
>   'ForeignKey: Message {'TopicID'} -> Topic {'TopicID'} ToDependent:
>   Messages ToPrincipal: Topic, ForeignKey: Topic {'MessageID'} ->
>   Message {'MessageID'} ToPrincipal: Message'.
>            at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.Multigraph'2.BatchingTopologicalSort(Func'2
>   formatCycle)
>            at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.CommandBatchPreparer.TopologicalSort(IEnumerable'1
>   commands)
>            at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.CommandBatchPreparer.d__8.MoveNext()
>            at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(Tuple'2
>   parameters)
>            at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState
>   state, Func'3 operation, Func'3 verifySucceeded)
>            at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(IEnumerable'1
>   commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection)
>            at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalDatabase.SaveChanges(IReadOnlyList'1
>   entries)
>            at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(IReadOnlyList'1
>   entriesToSave)
>            at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean
>   acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
>            at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean
>   acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)

What am I doing wrong?

How can I create in one connection to the db the topic and message with each-other's right foreign keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make Topic.MainMessage optional, and set it after you have SaveChanges()ed the Topic.Messages.

Comment: but if i set it after context.SaveChanges() it means i would take me 2 connections to create a new topic & message. is there a way to do it in 1 connection?

Comment: Just one connection.  Two separate commands.  And no, there's no other way (without dropping or disabling the foreign keys).

Comment: isn't Topic.MainMessage already optional unless i set it with IsRequired()? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/required-optional

Comment: In addition to being optional it has to _actually be null_ when you save the Topic.

Comment: great this works! i have another question though regarding your comment that said this is one connection: when i run 2 context.SaveChanges() doesn't it open 2 connections?